# C#; listbox's as one object(container)

Tags: c#, listbox

I use Visual studio 2008 
I have 5 listbox's on form,I created a new class  file -called him  "scaner.cs"

scaner.cs -he cannot  see "listbox".

I have create an instance.

  `scaner Comp = new scaner(listBox2, listBox1, listBox3, listBox4, listBox5);`

In scaner.cs file I use it like this.

```
class scaner
    {
        public ListBox ls;
        public ListBox lsE;
        public ListBox lsIVars;
        public ListBox lsNumbers;
        public ListBox lsStrings;

public scaner(ListBox ls, ListBox lsE, ListBox lsIVars, ListBox lsNumbers, ListBox lsStrings)
        {
            this.ls = ls;
            this.lsE = lsE;
            this.lsIVars = lsIVars;
            this.lsNumbers = lsNumbers;
            this.lsStrings = lsStrings;
        }
}
```

My question : How can i replaced this big code to more "comfortably" method.

```
scaner Comp = new scaner(listBox2, listBox1, listBox3, listBox4, listBox5);
```

IF i had more then 5 listbox's ,it will be awful.
How can i acced form another class file "Listbox's"
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a field to store all the `ListBox` instances and then change the constructor to accept an arbitrary number of them:

```
class scaner
{
    readonly IEnumerable<ListBox> listBoxes;

    public IEnumerable<ListBox> ListBoxes
    {
        get { return this.listBoxes; }
    }

    public scaner(params ListBox[] listBoxes)
    {
        this.listBoxes = listBoxes;    
    }
}
```

This will allow you to do this:

```
scaner Comp = new scaner(listBox1, listBox2);
```

or this:

```
// Here I am passing 4 ListBoxes - you can pass as many as you wish
// without modifying the source code of your scaner class
scaner Comp = new scaner(listBox1, listBox2, listBox3, listBox4);
```

Comment: @Oyeme: this.listBoxes[0] or just listBoxes[0]

Answer (score 1):

Use `List<ListBox>`